# How to reset default location map of Nerddinner?

Tags: dictionary, bing

It's a simple issue which I want to modify for a long time.

Could anyone let me know where I could change the default map location from "USA" to "UK" or other country?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you just supply it with a desired Latitude and Longitude, and it will center on that point.

You might find this of interest:

**Virtual Earth JavaScript Intellisense Helper** 
http://www.codeplex.com/VEJS

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem (this is in C#)

```
Bing.Maps.Location loc = new Bing.Maps.Location()
            {
                Latitude = yourlatitude
                Longitude = yourlongitude
            };
            map.SetView(loc, 12);
```